# Web Scraping in R using XML and Rvest

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I am trying to scrape congress member grades from the NIAC website. Here is a link of a sample representative: https://www.niacaction.org/legislator-bio/?bid=C001097

My end goal is to have a data frame with the Congress Member's name, state, distract, and then their grades for the 113th-115th Congress. I am using XML and rvest to do this. Here is my code:

```
####----- Load Packages -----####
library('rvest')
library('XML')

####----- Scrape -----####
url <- 'https://www.niacaction.org/legislator-bio/?bid=C001097'

nodes <- read_html(url, xpath = '//h3 | //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " 
" ), concat( " ", "entry-title", " " ))]')


page <- htmlTreeParse(nodes)
```

When I print what I have called "page" I am getting a lot more information than I want. I don't understand why because I clearly identified the xpath. Any input would be much appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XML::htmlTreeParse` is the equivalent of `xml2::read_html` (used by rvest), which does not accept XPath—for that, use `rvest::html_nodes`. Use one package or the other; crossing them will get messy. rvest also accepts CSS selectors, which lets you simplify neatly:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)    # for munging; translate if you like

url <- 'https://www.niacaction.org/legislator-bio/?bid=C001097'

page <- url %>% read_html()

cardenas <- page %>% {
    data_frame(member = html_node(., 'h1') %>% html_text(),
               grade = html_nodes(., 'h3') %>% html_text())
} %>% 
    separate(grade, c('congress', 'grade'), sep = ' Grade: ') %>% 
    separate(member, c('member', 'info'), sep = ' \\(') %>% 
    separate(info, c('party', 'state', 'district'), extra = 'drop', convert = TRUE) 

cardenas
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>              member party state district       congress grade
#> *             <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int>          <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Rep Tony Cárdenas     D    CA       29        Current     A
#> 2 Rep Tony Cárdenas     D    CA       29 115th Congress     A
#> 3 Rep Tony Cárdenas     D    CA       29 114th Congress     C
#> 4 Rep Tony Cárdenas     D    CA       29 113th Congress     D
```